# What is the correct Excel Application type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, csv

I have an MVC app that will download some data to an Excel file. I'm having a hard time figuring out what the correct application type should be.

In the following code you can see all the different application types I've tried and the only one I've found that works is uncommented. I have to use a .csv file extension and I would prefer to use .xls or .xlsx instead.

When I try anything with the .xls extension it will return but each line will be placed in the first cell as apposed to spererated into each column. If I use the .xlsx extension I get an error that it's the wrong extension type and then nothing shows up at all.

Using the .csv extension with the vnd.ms.excel type works correctly. It's just the file extension is .csv instead of .xls or .xlsx which would be preferred. Any idea why .xls or .xlsx is not working?

```
public FileResult ExcelDownload()
        {
            List<Employee> lstEmployee = new List<Employee>();

            try
            {
                lstEmployee = DataManager.GetData();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error("Error while getting data. Error: {0} | Trace: {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            }


            var sbItem = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            if (lstEmployee != null && lstEmployee.Count > 0)
            {
                logger.Debug("Excel record count: " + lstEmployee.Count);

                int rank = 1;
                sbItem.AppendLine("Seniority,Co,CityCode,Employee,LastName,FirstName,JobTitle,EmployType,SeniorityDate,LOA,TWA");
                foreach (Employee e in lstEmployee)
                {
                    //Add the seniority rank to each employee
                    e.SeniorityRank = rank;

                    sbItem.AppendLine(e.SeniorityRank + "," + 
                        e.Co + "," + 
                        e.CityCode + "," + 
                        e.EmployeeNumber + "," + 
                        e.FirstName + "," + 
                        e.LastName + "," + 
                        e.Position + "," + 
                        e.EmploymentType + "," +
                        string.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", e.SeniorityDate) + "," + 
                        e.LOA);

                    rank += 1;
                }
            }

            return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(sbItem.ToString()), "application/vnd.ms-excel", "SeniorityList.csv");

            //return new File(sbItem.ToString(), "application/vnd.ms-excel", "SeniorityList.xls");
            //return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(sbItem.ToString()), "text/csv", "SeniorityList.csv");
            //return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(sbItem.ToString()), "vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet ", "SeniorityList.xlsx");

        }
```

Comment: For `xlsx` files (real ones, not `cvs` claiming to be `xlsx`) I use `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

Comment: But if you really want Excel to see you file as an *actual Excel file* then you need to send an actual Excel file.